# Find new coordinates of point on line in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, geometry, trigonometry

Let's say I have two points which I know: x1,y1 and x2,y2. I know I can easily calculate the length of this line with Pythagorean, but what if I want to calculate a shortened version of the line. For example, I would like the x,y coordinates 10 pixels toward the next point. Is there a simple formula for finding any new point on an angled line?

Comment: You're going to need to explain more thoroughly and add your code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Yes. The basic linear algebra stuff.   `(x-x1)/(y-y1) = (x2-x1)/(y2-y1)`

Comment: Tagging this as trig was a good start, you know the slope, so you can find the angle at one of the vertices, I think it's the arc tangent. Then you need something like 1/(sine theta) to get delta y and 1/(cosine theta) to get delta x.

Comment: Algebra won't work, since it's a distance along the hypotenuse that is 10 units.

Comment: @PeterWooster - Yes it will. Don't be ridiculous.

Comment: @PM77-1 The issue is that I don't know the new coordinates. Here is an example: Let's say I have two points [34,47] and [24, 31] and I want to find the new x/y coordinates 10 units from the first point to the second point.

Comment: @PM77 Given a length of 10 pixels along the line (hypotenuse) how do you find the distance along the x axis with simple algebra?  You might be able to do it by solving the inverse of pythagorus, but that is not simple.

Comment: @PeterWooster - My bad.  I was providing a solution for a different  problem. This one also have algebraic solution, but the equation wouldn't be linear.

Comment: @PM77, I agree there is a solution involving more square roots than I can handle this late at night.

Comment: Actually just a single square root involving `x1,y1` and `x2,y2` only.  Let's call the distance between these two points (calculated with Pythagorean) `w`.  The distance from `x,y` to `x2,y2` - `a` (in your case 10 pixels).  Then `a/w = (x1-x)/(y1-y)` and `(w-a)/w = (x2-x)/(y2-y)`.  Just a system of two linear equations.  Still easily solvable.

Comment: +1 in the light of the morning it is just similar triangles so ratio works, with one square root

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a generic Maths problem, not necessarily a programming question. I think http://math.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit.

Comment: @David Sorry, feel free to delete! I'm such an intruder here. I got the answer and posted solution above anyway.

Comment: @jrue this worked for me, thanks heaps!

Answer (score 18):

I've created a fiddle that utilizes a ratio of corresponding sides.  Adjust variable `smallerLen` to any unit to see the point move across the line.

http://jsfiddle.net/3SY8v/

Comment: Yep.  Seems like the same approach.

Comment: fantastic. I was up to the part of ratio, makes sense. Thanks everyone.

Comment: works perfeclty! thanks :D

Comment: Thanks for the example, appreciated